# Starting Tor Relay?

Tags: pluggable-transports

I am trying to run a tor relay. I have went to the torcc file and uncommented what I believe be. Then I exited tor, then I started the tor bundle pkg. So how do i know in linux system that the relay is working?

Answer (score 1):

Your Tor log will report that it has successfully been able to perform a self-connectivity test, then you will also be able to find it in the next consensus assuming it was voted into it. You can also see if it's in the consensus by looking for it on [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/).